# Sending message through SoapUI

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui

I opened my wsdl file locally with soapUI(not using my localhost url but directly showing the wsdl from my harddisc, using localhost url can not find schemas..!)

Anyway, it has loaded the wsdl, how can I send a message to my web service through soapUI?
I have the message to be send;

```
<holyrequest xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mywebsite.com/xml/webservice Request.xsd"
 xmlns="http://www.mywebsite.com/xml/webservice"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<state reached="false">
  <value>Plan</value>
    <myvariable>myplan</myvariable>
</state>

 </holyrequest>
```

I couldnt find a place to copy this message and start testing my web service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your wsdl is imported correctly, you should see all operations.
If you expand the operation you want to call, soap UI shows a default request (usually called "Request 1").  If you double-click that one, it will show an empty request generated by soapUI for your operation.
You can edit the request on the left before sending it.  The response will be shown on the right.

Comment: tnx, will i do that from testsuite, or mockservice or wsbinding menu? I see a branch called holy, Response 1, but no Request 1

Comment: How did you import the wsdl?  I usually do this via 'New soapUI project', selecting the wsdl and checking 'Create sample requests for all operations'.  That way soapUI generates the sample requests which you can open and modify before sending/testing.

Comment: I did what you said, but can't see where are the sample requests, lots of windows and branchs here; xsd's, schemas, porttypes....etc. but from where and how can I add my xml? also will I need to add only the element group starting with <state> or I have to copy paste all te xml above? tnx verymuch

Comment: What are these responses? Maybe you can re-send those?

Comment: Ok now Found the request, but after sending it I have response failed error, I think my soap body message is not correct? I copy pasted the above xml directly under soap:body is that enough?

Comment: You cannot replace it entirely, it should still be in a soap envelope.  Normally, the soapUI generated request should already have that.  You should probably just replace some values in it.

Comment: it only says this, how will I edit this: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body/>
</soapenv:Envelope>